# Array of arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm using the %% operator on PostgreSQL's `hstore` type which converts a hstore (key-value type effectively) into an array whose elements alternate {{key, value}, {key value}}.

When I want to return array of these flattened hstores I get this error: `could not find array type for data type text[]`due to PostgreSQL lack of support for an array of arrays.

From a curiosity standpoint, does anyone know why these are not supported? And more importantly, is there a work around for this type of scenario?

At the moment I'm concatenating the results into a string (comma separated) and parsing them on the application (C# and NPGSQL) side. However, this approach doesn't feel quite right, I'd like to be able to read the row back as a .NET array of arrays or array of key-values etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: In the title we have a [false premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_premise), see [this answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10518236/287948): PostgreSQL supports array of arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> From a curiosity standpoint, does anyone know why these are not supported?

One generic answer is because arrays are intrinsically anti-relational. Removing repeating values is how you achieve [1st normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF). To have repeating groups of repeating groups seems quite insane from a relational theoretical standpoint.

In general, the relationally-correct thing to do is to extract a table for your repeating values. So if you modeled something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar,
  favorite_colors varchar[],
  ...
);
```

it would behoove you to redefine this relationally like so:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE favorite_colors (
  user_id integer references users,
  color varchar
);
```

Or even:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE colors (
  color varchar primary key
);

CREATE TABLE favorite_colors (
  user_id integer references users,
  color varchar references colors,
  primary key (user_id, color)
);
```

Hstore supports a lot of functions, many of which would make it easy to integrate it into a relational worldview. I think the simplest way to solve your problem would be to use the `each` function to convert your hstore values into relations you can then use like a normal set of values. This is how you address having multiple values in other databases anyway: querying, and working with result sets.

Comment: OPS! PostgreSQL support array of arrays (see my answer)... Yes, before read I not understand some PostgreSQL's behavours, but *it is about the constraint of uniformity of arrays*, that cause problems if you want, for instance, map JSON into an uniform multidimensional array. The uniformity constraint ensures something like _normal forms_, but not exactly the 1st one.

Comment: "One generic answer is because arrays are intrinsically anti-relational. Removing repeating values is how you achieve 1st normal form." Nonsense. You are mixing up two different definitions of "repeating". One definition implies non-uniqueness/redundancy. The other implies you have a series of data (some form of vector). A string is an array of characters. That doesn't mean it's internally repeating, redundant or a poor representation of the value it holds.

Comment: @HannesLandeholm You are confusing the internal representation with the relational representation. Every database has `varchar`; few have arrays. This is sensible because nobody uses strings as arrays. They are treated as atomic values.

Answer (score 25):

### PostgreSQL has limited "array of arrays" support

[see manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html)

It is a restricted form of "array of arrays". As Pavel (answer) says, it is named "multidimensional array" but is really a matrix, so it must have the same number of elements in each dimension.

You can use this kind of structure for map multidimensional and heterogeneous cartesian coordinates in scientific applications, but not to store arbitrary vectors of vectors like a XML or JSON data.

NOTE: a well-known 2-dimensional (2D) homogeneous array is the [mathematical matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)). In fact, the scientific applications of matrix that motivated the "PostgreSQL constrained multidimensional array" datatype, and the array functions behaviour with these kind of arrays. Think about "3D array" as a "3D matrix", "4D array" as a "4D matrix", and so on.

EXAMPLES:

```
SELECT array_cat(ARRAY[[1,2],[3,4]], ARRAY[5,6]);
---------------------
 {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}
SELECT array_cat(ARRAY[[1,2],[3,4]], ARRAY[[5,6]]); -- SAME RESULT

SELECT ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2],ARRAY[5,6]];
---------------
 {{1,2},{5,6}}

SELECT array_cat(ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2]],ARRAY[3]); -- ERROR1
SELECT ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2],ARRAY[4]];  -- ERROR2
```

The comments of @Daniel_Lyons about "why these are not supported" is about "non-uniform arrays of arrays" (see error cases above).
`ERROR1` above: because can only concatenate arrays of same dimension
`ERROR2` above: all arrays for a specific dimension must have the same length, like a matrix.

Another curious thing  about build-in functions and operators: the "default behaviour" in PostgreSQL is for single arrays and elements. There are no overload for standard `array_append()`,

```
SELECT array_append(ARRAY[1,2],5); -- now ok, 5 is a element
 {1,2,5}

SELECT array_cat(ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[5,6]);
----------
 {1,2,5,6}

SELECT array_append(ARRAY[[1,2],[3,4]], ARRAY[5,6]); -- ERROR3 
SELECT array_append(ARRAY[1,2],ARRAY[5,6]); -- ERROR4
```

`ERROR3` above: there are NO OVERLOAD to append "array element" (even 9.2 pg version).
`ERROR4` above: must use array_cat to "merge all in one array".

The "merge behaviour" of the last `array_cat` example is curious, not  produced array of arrays.  Use `array_cat(a1, ARRAY[a2])` for achieve this result,

```
SELECT array_cat(ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[ARRAY[5,6]]);  -- seems illogical...
---------------
{{1,2},{5,6}}
```

---

### Sparse matrix

To avoid problems with [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) and similar data structures, use the function below. It fills the remaining elements, setting then to NULL (or to any constant value).

```
 CREATE or replace FUNCTION array_fillTo(
    p_array anyarray, p_len integer, p_null anyelement DEFAULT NULL
 ) RETURNS anyarray AS $f$
   SELECT CASE 
       WHEN len=0 THEN array_fill(p_null,array[p_len])
       WHEN len<p_len THEN p_array || array_fill($3,array[$2-len])
       ELSE $1 END
   FROM ( SELECT COALESCE( array_length(p_array,1), 0) ) t(len)
 $f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

PS: please edit this answer to add any corrections/optimizations, it is a Wiki!

Returning to the first examples, now we can avoid errors (see ERROR1),

```
SELECT array_cat(ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2]],array_fillTo(ARRAY[3],2));
-- {{1,2},{3,NULL}}
SELECT array_cat(
   ARRAY[ARRAY[1.1::float,2.0]],
   array_fillTo(ARRAY[]::float[],2,0::float)
);
-- {{1.1,2},{0,0}}
SELECT array_fillto(array['Hello'],2,'');
-- {Hello,""}
```

---

**NOTE about old array_fillTo()**

The `array_fill()` become a buildin function with PostgreSQL v8.4, for v8.3 or olds:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION array_fillTo(anyarray,integer,anyelement DEFAULT NULL) 
 RETURNS anyarray AS $$
   DECLARE
     i integer;
     len integer;
     ret ALIAS FOR $0;
   BEGIN
     len = array_length($1,1);
     ret = $1;
     IF len<$2 THEN
         FOR i IN 1..($2-len) LOOP
           ret = ret || $3;
         END LOOP;
     END IF;
     RETURN ret;
   END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: It is not so useful as [JSONb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), but sometimes is possible to use **ARRAY of ROWs**... See the  `ARRAY[ROW(g.f1, g.f2)]` example at [pg Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).

Comment: To unnest use [reduce_dim()](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Unnest_multidimensional_array)

Comment: `unnest` is a useful  to flatten an `n-dimensional` matrix: `SELECT unnest(ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2,3],ARRAY[4,5,6]]);`returns `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` (you get the same result even if your matrix has higher dimensions: `SELECT unnest(ARRAY[ARRAY[ARRAY[1],ARRAY[2],ARRAY[3]],ARRAY[ARRAY[4],ARRAY[5],ARRAY[6]]]);`)

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL support a multidimensional arrays instead - arrays are relative very special type in relational databases and it is little bit limited against general programming languages. If you need it, you can use a workaround with row arrays:

```
postgres=# create table fx(a int[]);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into fx values(array[1,3,4]);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into fx values(array[6,7]);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select array_agg(row(a)) from fx;
            array_agg            
---------------------------------
 {"(\"{1,3,4}\")","(\"{6,7}\")"}
(1 row)
```