# Accessing array-item from array of arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql

So simple... I need to retrieve an item of an array-of-arrays, so the item must be a simple array.  Example:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT '{{1,2,3},{333,444,555}}'::int[][] as a, '{{{{1,2}}}}'::int[] as b)
SELECT 
     a[2],    -- returns null (!), why not works?
     a[2:2],  -- returns array-into-array, not simple array
     b[1][1], -- also null
     b[1][1][1:2],  -- another ugly array-into-array-into...-array
     a[1][1]        -- is correct, but only works with scalars
FROM t;
```

The result is `NULL,{{333,444,555}},NULL,{{{{1,2}}}},1`... I need a simple array for *a[2]*, `{333,444,555}`... **How to access it as it?**

PS: the [guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html) and google-examples only show slices... Perhaps it is so obvious but I not remember why `a[2]` is invalid in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please note that you are casting 2-dimensional arrays into an array of a single dimension for `a`, and a 4-dimension array into a single dimension for `b`. I believe you will need to create a function to perform the extraction `a[2]` the way you expect.

Comment: Hi @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, thanks. Well... if you change the code, `'{{1,2,3},{333,444,555}}'::int[][]` with more one `[]`, the result is the same... I think that I not understand your point.

Comment: Sorry, it was late night here. I somewhat misunderstood you question. The types casts are wrong, but even fixing them, you need an specialized function to extract a single array from a n-dimension array.

Comment: Thanks @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, I edited, changing `int[]` to `int[][]` and, after also testing, unfortunately (I am using stable pg9.4), the problem is the same.

Comment: The only solution is to write a function for this (through PL/SQL or C).

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira ... Hum (no solution!?)...  more one item for my  pg-wish-list :-)      Why the PostgreSQL community adopted a so ugly convention?  Why `a[2]` is NULL? .... I was also looking for an array-extract-item-as-it operator, but I didn't find it in the guide.

Answer (score 1):

[I had forgotten what we discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10518236/287948): it is a restricted form of "array of arrays"... named "multidimensional array"...  But I persisted in thinking in ambiguous way, that is, thinking sometimes in array of arrays...

The best answer comes from Tom Lane at the pgsql-hackers.at.postgresql.org forum, *"Multi-dimensional arrays in Postgres are **not** 'arrays of arrays'"*.

So, in the "multidimensional array" world, not exist that kind of "access to an array-item" that I expected.

---

As @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira commented here, the only solution is to write a function, through PL/SQL (low performance) or C (high performance).

Answer (score 0):

**`a[2:2]`** will return **`integer[]`** type, while non-colon notation **`a[2]`** will return **`integer`** type, which in fact in your case should be an array. Based on the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html):

> An array slice is denoted by writing **lower-bound:upper-bound** for **one**
>   or **more** array dimensions.

Check the code below:

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT
      '{
        {11,12,13},
        {21,22,23},
        {31,32,33},
        {41,42,43}
       }'::INTEGER[][] as vv
)
SELECT
  array_dims(vv) dimensions,--  [1:4][1:3] - get all dimensions
  vv[1:4] all_slices, -- entire 2d-array
  vv[2:3] second_and_third_slices, -- {{21,22,23},{{31,32,33}}
  vv[2:2] second_slice, -- {{21,22,23}} - get specific slice
  pg_typeof(vv[2:2]) second_slice_type, -- type of slice above is INTEGER[]!
  pg_typeof(vv[2]) vv_type, -- type is INTEGER
  vv[2:2][2:2] second_slice_second_element, -- 22 - get specific element
  vv[2:2][2:3] second_slice_second_and_third_elements -- {{22,23}}
FROM test;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks (!).  Your `vv[2:2] second_slice` is my `a[2]`, and you do exactly the same thing, that is not a solution.  Your `vv[2:2]`  returns `{{21,22,23}}` , but I need a simple access method that returns `{21,22,23}`... the question is "How to access it as it?".