# How to store 2D array in postgresql using C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, postgresql

I want save 2-dim array in postgresql some like this: `int[,] arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};`

I am using the following `sql statement` which is working fine to 1-dim array, but it is not work for 2-dim array.

```
try
{
    string sql1 = "INSERT INTO tbtest(col) VALUES (ARRAY[" + string.Join(", ", arr) + "])";

    dbcmd.CommandText = sql1;
    dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (NpgsqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Data == null)
    {
        throw;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159440/array-of-arrays-in-postgresql for multidimensional arrays. The `ARRAY[]` should have adjusted for multidimensional format.

Comment: How can you retrieve the value back? please answer in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49489372/c-sharp-retrieve-text-type-from-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method

```
 int[,] arr = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };   
 var arrayOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr);
 string query = "INSERT INTO tbtest(col) VALUES (ARRAY" + arrayOutput + ")";
```

Output

> INSERT INTO tbtest(col) VALUES (ARRAY[[1,2],[3,4]])

Comment: what was the error in JsonConvert? You need to add NewtonSoft.Json from Nuget package .

Comment: error: the name `JsonConver` does not exit in the current context

Comment: you need to add NewtonSoft.Json Dll.

Comment: I did not find NewtonSoft.Json Dll Net 4.5. Can you send the link

Comment: you can add this package using Nuget

Comment: I upgrade NuGet and Solved. Thank you my brother.

Comment: But, I have another problem. How to store the result of SURF in postgresql?