# c# retrieve _text type from postgresql

Tags: c#, database, postgresql

I have a array like [["64", "0", "0"], ["64", "7", "95"], ["61", "28", "165"], ["60", "45", "200"]] in Postgres column which I stored from ruby on rails, and I want to retrieve it in my C# project. When I do this:

```
NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetString(1));
}
```

I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type _text to String
> How can I get this column value as an Array
> But when I do:

```
dt.Load(reader);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{                
    var points = row["points"];
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(points);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

it returns ["64","0","0","64","7","95","61","28","165","60","45","200"] which is not what I want.

Comment: Why the `sqlite` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
string[,] result = row["points"] as string[,];
```

pgSql has an array field defined, so it cannot convert to string directly.

Comment: please edit the answer to: string[,] result = row["points"] as string[,]; so that i can mark it as correct.. The array is 2 dimensional so it needs to be string[,]

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake and thank you for the correction!